# Trying to redirect user after login in Symfony using targetPath but it is always null

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony-3.4

I've seen that `$this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)` can be used to get the target path but it is always `null`.

Can someone explain what it is meant to do and why it is always `null` for me?

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;


class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{

    use TargetPathTrait;

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
        {
            $targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey);

            if (!$targetPath) {
                $targetPath = $this->container->get('router')
                    ->generate('poll_index');
            }

            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }
}
```

Comment: Looking at symfony's source code, the only time target path is set is when the user start the authentication flow, passing through the entry point. With the `FormAuthenticationEntryPoint` this is usually when you try to access a restricted page, and you are (usually) redirected to the login page. Is it what you are doing in this case as well? Trying to hit a restricted page before anything else?

Comment: Ah I see, I'm not redirecting from a restricted page. The user can view some public information on a page, and click a login to be taken to the login form. I want to then take the user back to the page they were on before login, which will then show the restricted content. I have another question about how I've implemented that and the error I've encountered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464829/redirect-to-page-prior-to-login-form-symfony-3-4-is-resolving-to-liip-imagine-ro

Comment: That looks good enough for an answer if you can pad it out with the code you found that sets it.

Comment: How did you solve this? I used the Security Bundle also and the generated code does not work for redirects after login. Did you have to set the value somewhere?

Comment: @Isengo This is how I solved it (see comment above): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464829/redirect-to-page-prior-to-login-form-symfony-3-4-is-resolving-to-liip-imagine-ro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only time `target path` is set from Symfony is when the user start the authentication flow, passing through the authentication entry point. This is done by the [ExceptionListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php#L182). If you are using the `FormAuthenticationEntryPoint`, this happens when you try to access a restricted page, and you are (usually) redirected to the login page. At that point `target path` is set.

Usually there's no reason to set it yourself, but you could do so by using TargetPathTrait's saveTargetPath like so:

```
$this->saveTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey, $request->getUri());
```

Comment: Hold on, that is what I'm doing isn't it? I have `$this->saveTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey, $request->getUri());` at the start of the method, but if I `dump($targetPath)` immediately after I call it, it dumps `null`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm using `getTargetPath()`. So, maybe I could `saveTargetPath()` on entering the login controller, and set it to be the referring page?

Comment: yep, that should do